# Rails 4 Unitwise Gem how can I access the list of possible unit types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, units-of-measurement

I am using this gem to add units/amounts to my models.  https://github.com/joshwlewis/unitwise.
I followed a great tutorial here http://joshwlewis.com/essays/rails-unit-measurement-persistence/.

What I can not figure out is how to access the list of units that are available.  When creating a new model, I would like my User to be able to select the unit type that they want to save the amount in.

Has anyone needed to do this before?

Comment: Couldn't you pull the data from the `.yaml` files in the data folder into an array of hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units appear to be defined in data/base_unit.yaml and data/derived_unit.yaml and they have classes Unitwise::Standard::BaseUnit and Unitwise::Standard::DerivedUnit respectively, that appear to be used to gather the data from those YAML files.

Using those classes you can do this:

```
Unitwise::Standard::BaseUnit.all.collect{|u| u.attributes['name']}
```

And

```
Unitwise::Standard::DerivedUnit.all.collect{|u| u.attributes['name']}
```

You may also have to do these require statements first:

```
require 'unitwise'
require 'unitwise/standard'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am attempting to set up a form where the user can select the unit type and then it will be saved using UnitWise.  Have you used UnitWise for this? I am not finding many resources on how to execute.

Comment: Sorry, your posting was the first I'd heard of Unitwise. It looks interesting though, and I'm grateful for you bringing it to my attention. I'd suggest you clone your own copy and then trim the derived_unit.yaml files down to the units you want to make available.

Answer (score 1):

Unitwise is designed such that it supports an infinite number of units. While completely irrational, you **could** create something like `Unitwise(1, "joule.kilopascal/foot.year")`. I'm probably being overly technical here, but the number of units is not finite, so we can't list them all. However, you can get a list of component atoms like this:

```
require 'unitwise'
Unitwise::Atom.all
# => [#<Unitwise::Atom names=["meter"], primary_code="m", secondary_code="M", symbol="m", scale=nil, classification=nil, property="length", metric=true, special=false, arbitrary=false, dim="L">, ...]
```

Or you can also get all the possible combinations of atoms and prefixes like this:

```
Unitwise::Compound.all
# => [#<Unitwise::Compound atom='m', prefix='', primary_code='m', secondary_code='M', symbol='m', names='["meter"]', slugs='["meter"]'>, ...]
```

And lastly, if you are searching for something particular use this:

```
Unitwise.search('degree')
# => [#<Unitwise::Compound atom='Cel', prefix='', primary_code='Cel', secondary_code='CEL', symbol='°C', names='["degree Celsius"]', slugs='["degree_celsius"]'>, ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming late to the party, but perhaps this can be useful for someone in the future.

As Josh said (thank you for the awesome lib BTW) each UOM is represented by an atom. This is an atom sample:

```
[#<Unitwise::Atom names=["meter"], primary_code="m", secondary_code="M",symbol="m", scale=nil, classification=nil, property="length", metric=true, special=false, arbitrary=false, dim="L">, ...]
```

So if you like to filter, you can do it based on the properties, which are fairly standard. In my case I was interested on units of weight, so I scraped the constants too.

```
Unitwise::Atom.all.select { |m| m.property == 'weight' }
                  .select { |m| m.classification != 'const' }
```

I still ending up with a lot of obscure units, so I just specified manually the ones I needed, like this, for grams, tonnes, pounds and ounces:

```
Unitwise::Atom.all.select { |m| m.property == 'weight' }
                  .select { |m| m.classification != 'const' }
                  .select { |m| ['g','t','[lb_av]','[oz_av]'].include?(m.primary_code) }
```

**Huge disclaimer:** I am pretty new on Rails so I am sure this code can be greatly improved, but you get the idea.